# Firebase storage FirebaseApiNotAvailableException repeatedly in the log when offline

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I'm using:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.1"
```

And this is the code that I execute this with the device **offline** (no internet):

```
StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl([MY_URL]);
mStorageRef.child("my_file.json").getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE)
 .addOnSuccessListener(bla bla bla).addOnFailureListener(more bla bla)
```

I get this message repeated in my log **every second**:

```
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: firebase-auth is not linked, please fall back to unauthenticated mode.
```

Is this a bug or expected behavior? 
I know that if I'm offline, I won't get the remote file, but why is firebase code trying to poll every second?

**Note**: when I get online again it executes the success/failure listener and finishes polling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for the log overload. The first (`W/ExponenentialBackoff`) needs to be pared down quite a bit (we're planning on better client side logging in the future), while the second (`E/StorageUtil`) can be prevented by linking Firebase Authentication in the app's build.gradle file:

`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0"`.

Comment: when you say "linking Firebase Authentication", does that mean just adding the dependency in the gradle file or do I have to do anything else? My Firebase stored file has rules for reading public access (no write permissions). Thanks for the response!

Comment: All you have to do is link the dependency to make the error go away, though you're correct that if you have everything public read/write you don't need auth. In the future we'll remove that from the logs.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald I'm having the exact same issue with the OP, and the auth dependency didn't fix that. The onFailure() listener does not get called if the user is not connected to the Internet, so how will we catch that event?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Anything new regarding this?

Comment: @AlaaM. have you tried upgrading to 10.x? The latest is `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'`

Comment: @MikeMcDonald I'm getting a **Failed to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1** for this version.

Comment: Have you updated Google Play Services to that version?

Comment: Updated Google Play Services to 10.0.1 as well and the OP's problem still exists. **ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.** keeps firing every second. My log is flooded...

Comment: I get the same behaviour even now with 11.0.4 :( Probably the only workaround is to check internet connectivity before trying to auth....

Comment: Nothing solved yet. Still having this issue on 16.0.1.

Comment: After this, you might encounter this other problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057798/firebase-token-authentication-error?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Google Play services updated to **9.0.2** The Google Play services version 9.0.2 release is now available. This release fixes a known issue with Firebase Authentication where the **FirebaseAuthApi** is not available on some devices. A **FirebaseApiNotAvailableException** error occurs when those devices attempt to use Authentication APIs.