# Firebase storage URL error token

Tags: android, error-handling, firebase-storage

```
 try {
                    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(storage.getReferenceFromUrl(reference).getDownloadUrl().getResult().toString()).getContent();
                    d = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
```

I'm trying to download multiples pictures from Firebase storage at the same time. Now I'm trying to do it this way after putting this method in a loop but it keeps giving me this error

```
E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzanu: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057798/firebase-token-authentication-error and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374868/firebase-getdownloadurl too

Comment: But the main problem was with the listeners cause when I put a listener on a loop it gives me an Error saying maximum threads 128 pool something like that

Comment: Sure, but that's not why this is failing initially. It looks like you either: haven't authenticated or haven't set your security rules to allow unauthenticated access.