# Firebase Storage upload issues despite rules set to public

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

My app contains this feature where you can upload photos online. I am using Firebase Storage, but upload is too slow. Sometimes it lasts more than 10-15 seconds for one photo that has average quality. Also am I getting this message for like 6 times in log cat when trying to upload photo:

```
E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqn: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
```

Those are rules set for my Firebase Storage:

```
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write;
}
```

Is it possible that this exception is related to slow uploading of the photo? I don't want to use Firebase authentication, only Firebase storage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Token Authentication error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057798/firebase-token-authentication-error)

Comment: @FrancescoStranieri Solution from the link you posted is suggesting firebase auth which I don't want to use at the moment. Besides, question from that link doesn't have detailed description as much as this one I posted. Go and get cheap reputation points somewhere else

Comment: It doesn't appear as though you're getting a `403` which would indicate you have bad rules, so I doubt that error has anything to do with your rules or the slow upload time. Slow uploads are more likely a symptom of poor internet connections more than anything else, so I'd check your network first.