# Fetching Image Issue from firebase using Picasso

Tags: java, android, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I have done with the text feteching from the database, buit while fetching image from the database using picasso the images are not loading the phone and the logcat is displaying the error :

```
com.example.lenovo.skanda E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
```

The textviews are easily getting fetching from the firebase. But in case of ImageView its not loading properly.

**QuoteList.java**

```
public class QuoteList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StorageReference storageRef;

    RecyclerView  mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference mReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote_list);

        //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Quotes");
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.quotes_list);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Quotes");
    }





    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Quote, QuoteViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Quote, QuoteViewHolder>(
                        Quote.class,
                        R.layout.quote_row,
                        QuoteViewHolder.class,
                        mReference
                ) {

                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(QuoteViewHolder viewHolder , Quote model , int position) {

                     //   viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getQuotes(), model.getQuote_Author(), model.getImages());
                            viewHolder.setQuotes(model.getQuotes());
                            viewHolder.setQuoteAuthor(model.getQuote_Author());
                            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImages());


                    }
                };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    public static class QuoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;

        public QuoteViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setQuotes(String Quote){
            TextView post_quote = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_quote);
            post_quote.setText(Quote);
        }

        public void setQuoteAuthor(String QuoteAuthor){
            TextView post_quoteAuthor = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_author);
            post_quoteAuthor.setText(QuoteAuthor);
        }

        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
            ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            Picasso.get().load(image).into(post_image);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

I am also attaching the logcat error report. Please go through it.

```
    11-04 16:16:37.413 6688-7596/com.example.lenovo.skanda E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
11-04 16:16:39.547 6688-7596/com.example.lenovo.skanda E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
11-04 16:16:40.567 6688-7596/com.example.lenovo.skanda E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
11-04 16:16:41.948 6688-7596/com.example.lenovo.skanda E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
11-04 16:16:44.661 6688-7596/com.example.lenovo.skanda E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
11-04 16:16:48.528 6688-7603/com.example.lenovo.skanda E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
11-04 16:24:46.716 6688-6698/com.example.lenovo.skanda E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
11-04 16:24:46.717 6688-6698/com.example.lenovo.skanda E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.isClosed()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.free(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:986)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1014)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:252)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:239)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:105)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.isClosed()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.free(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:986)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1014)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:252)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:239)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:105)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
11-04 16:24:46.718 6688-6698/com.example.lenovo.skanda E/System: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.isClosed()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.free(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:986)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1014)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:252)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:239)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:105)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.isClosed()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.free(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:986)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1014)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:252)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:239)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:105)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057798/firebase-token-authentication-error?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the follwing error:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.

Because by default, your are security rules require your user to be authenticated.

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

To solve this, you can either make sure your user is authenticated before trying to diplay the image or change the security rules to:

```
allow read, write;
```

But I recommend you to use these rules only for testing purposes. Don't keep this rules always like this. Secure your Firebase realtime database, as well as Firebase Storage.

Comment: Hi itz! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Why do you say that? Do you have the same error or another error? What is the behaviour?

Comment: Is the code below is proper for fetching Image from the database..?

 public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
            ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            Picasso.get().load(image).into(post_image);

Comment: In those lines of code, I cannot see any code related on getting data from the database. Please tell me, are you still getting that error (FirebaseNoSignedInUserException)?

Comment: No @Alex.. So how to add lines related to getting image url from the database

Comment: If the initial error disappeared, this are good news :) but `So how to add lines related to getting image url from the database` sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.