# How to create a custom directory in internal storage to save the downloaded file?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-internal-storage

Am working with firebase for an app. I have manually uploaded a pdf file into the firebase storage so that the users could download it using the app. The downloaded files gets stored in **Android -> data -> FileName -> directory -> file**. But I need a custom directory to save the files directly in the internal storage.

```
   public void downloadFile(){
        str = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        final File mydir = this.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;

    ref = str.child("AI (presentation).pptx");
        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String url = uri.toString();
                downloadFiles(MainActivity.this,"AI",".ppt",mydir ,url);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
}

public void downloadFiles(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtension, File destinationDirectory, String url) {

    DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, "" + destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtension);

    downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use DownloadManager.
Instead of that, you can use StorageReferenece.getBytes() and save file manually.

```
    private static final long DOWNLOAD_LIMIT = 1024 * 1024; // you can change this

    public void downloadFile(){
        StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("AI (presentation).pptx");
        ref.getBytes(DOWNLOAD_LIMIT).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/mydir/AI (presentation).pptx";
                try {
                    writeToFile(bytes, path);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "fail to download: " + exception);
            }
        });
    }

    public void writeToFile(byte[] data, String fileName) throws IOException{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But it shows an error **E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.**

Comment: You need an authentication step. Please refer to this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057798/firebase-token-authentication-error

or can change permissions of your firebase storage like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45501575/9683573

Comment: I changed the rules in firebase but it still shows the same :-(

Comment: Did you include google-service.json in your project?
If not, do this first. https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?authuser=0&hl=en
And then, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41441713/9683573