# error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to save an image to FireBase storage but I get an error saying:

`E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.`

I have tried following the [FireBase tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth?utm_source=studio) to authenticate anonymously but it still gives the same error

Comment: Did you find the problem? I am facing the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I fixed once I added this line:

```dart
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
```

based on [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41441713/13727011)

Answer (score -1):

Error clearly says that the problem is due to sign related issue. 
 means if the user is able to sign-in and getting the error.
  then the rule in Firebase storage is not as it is excepting.

[here are doc for firebase srorage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start)