# Firebase error when trying to get a file download url from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image file and get the image download URL using this code

```
    private void UploadImage() {
    String storageFileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"; // Time is used to ensure unique file name
    FireBase_File = FireBase_Storage.child(storageFileName);

    FireBase_File.putFile(UriBitmap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                FireBase_File.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FireBase_DownloadURL = task.getResult().toString();
                        } else { Log.e(Global.Log_Tag + "Manage_Restaurant/UploadImage", "Failed to get download url [Exception]" + task.getException()); }
                    }
                });
            } else { Log.e(Global.Log_Tag + "Manage_Restaurant/UploadImage", "Failed to upload image [Exception]" + task.getException()); }

            Finish_End();
        }
    });
}
```

and it worked fine until yesterday when I started getting this error messages in the console

> E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.

now I'm aware that this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057798/firebase-token-authentication-error) but I tried everything this threads suggested and it's not working. it's also worth noting that I'm not using the auth firebase system. I tried using the login anonymously suggestion and it gave me this error.

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This operation is restricted to administrators only.

all replies are appreciated!

Comment: Have you enabled anonymous signIn in Firebase Console?

Comment: I enabled it and it worked! thanks so much, I didn't know you need to activate it since I didn't use the auth system.

EDIT: I can't set this thread to solved... so I don't know what to do

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable anonymous auth for your Firebase project:

In the Firebase Console, **Auth -> Sign-in Methods** enable the **Anonymous** sign-in method.